# Encrypt ".mlapp" file of MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

How to encrypt ".mlapp" file of an application which is created by app designer ?

How can I encrypt a "**.mlapp**" file **without** using MATLAB Compiler ? I want to create an installation file of an application which is created by app designer and encrypt the source file of the application

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had answered a similar question before but I can't find it.

With App Designer you can export the app as .m code rather than a native .mlapp. You can then use `pcode` to obfuscate the source code.

Depending on the level of obfuscation you are looking for, another suitable method is that you keep app designer code free of as much code as possible, aside from function calls, and put it in to functions instead which you then run through `pcode`.

Comment: Thank you I understand, but if I export the app as .m code, is it possible to package it?

Comment: That's where my second option comes in. I've had the same problem that I'd like to obfuscate apps and also package them as apps. The second option allowed me to have some "viewable" code that basically just called obfuscated functions where all the "proprietary" code was contained.